# set the values of tag <select> html from database in php

Tags: php, html, database

the code below set the values of tag select from table department

```
<select name='dept'>
       <option value="">Select a department</option>

<?php
       $sql = "SELECT deptNo, deptName FROM Department";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo "<option value=$row[deptNo]";
```

this line below suppose to keep the selected value if the submit button failed BUT not working

```
if ($dept == $row["deptNo"]) echo 'selected="selected"';
   echo ">$row[deptName]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

the code is working fine except the problem mention above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($dept == $row["deptNo"]) echo ' selected="selected"';
```

a space in the echo statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT deptNo, deptName FROM Department";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $selected = ($dept == $row["deptNo"]) ? "selected" : "";
 ?>
<option value= "<?php echo $row['deptNo']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> >
   <?php echo $row['deptName']; ?>
</option>
<?php } } ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD